# M2Eclipse missing artfifact (it didn't check the local repository in ~user/.m2)

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

I added a jar with:

```
mvn install:install-file
  -Dfile=<path-to-file>
  -DgroupId=<group-id>
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
  -Dversion=<version>
  -Dpackaging=<packaging>
  -DgeneratePom=true
```

And added it as a dependency. M2eclipse went through the external repository URLs attempting to download the jar and failed. When and how will it check the local repository for the jar?

**Resolved:** don't mix up underscores and hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your user directory i.e. `C:\Profiles\youruser` there should be a folder called `.m2` may be hidden. Inside you can see whether that jar has been installed or not(although if the console says BUILD success you should be good).

Comment: The jar has been installed. M2Eclipse is saying Missing artifact on Maben Builder: AUTO_BUILD